# Symfony2 and Twig performance in a vagrant box

Tags: php, symfony, twig, vagrant, nfs

**Prerequisites:**

1. http://box.scotch.io/ vagrant box
  2.

```html
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1081, host: 1081
  config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../../../project", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666", "uid=1000", "gid=1000"], type: "nfs"
  #config.vm.synced_folder "./mysql", "/var/lib/mysql", :mount_options => ["dmode=700", "fmode=600", "uid=106", "gid=112"], type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../../../project/_conf", "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled", :mount_options => ["dmode=755", "fmode=644", "uid=0", "gid=0"], type: "nfs"

#############################


$script = <<SCRIPT
  sudo service apache2 restart && sudo service mysql start 
SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: false, run: "always"
end
```

3. A symfony2 project runs inside the box. Here is its require section of composer.json

```html
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "v1.1.0-alpha4",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "2.2.x-dev",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.1",
        "jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap": "2.3.1",
        "liip/theme-bundle": "dev-master",
        "fkr/cssurlrewrite-bundle": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-components": "dev-master#f096dd02136957ce1fba5819261a45b3ee9ed4a7",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "avalanche123/imagine-bundle": "v2.1",
        "r1pp3rj4ck/TwigstringBundle": "dev-master",
        "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "1.0.1"
    },
```

**Problem:**

When opening even an empty page like login form, it takes too long. As seen in profiler, the majority of time is taken by twig render:

[Twig taking 3.5 seconds to render](http://prntscr.com/59ko9z)

**What I have tried:**

1. as you see in Vagrantfile, NFS is enabled. Not sure how to test it
2. Read [this](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html) and [this](http://www.erikaheidi.com/blog/optimizing-symfony-applications-vagrant-boxes) . The test you see on the screenshot above was run after those changes are done

Comment: Does the first request and all the following requests take 3.5 seconds or only the first one? If it's only the first one, it's the creation of the cache which takes much time. Do you have a 5400 RPM HDD?

Comment: See below my answer, this was reproducible on all subsequent requests, so it was not a matter of cache initial generation. And I tested on SSD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make it work faster in vagrant in case your host OS is Win (Windows 7 x64 in my case), you need to:

1. add [this](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html) fix. I also added 'prod' environment to the list:

```php
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test', 'prod'))) {
        return '/dev/shm/project/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test', 'prod'))) {
        return '/dev/shm/project/logs';
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```

2. Fix I/O performance by utilizing NFS. The thing is that I was confused: setting nfs=true option in synced_folders does NOT mean you're connecting through NFS. My host OS is Win7 and I had to install [NFS server](http://www.hanewin.net/nfs-e.htm) in order to make it work. Note that it's not free.
   Here are two folders I had to share:

[image]

Also, mounting with synced_folder did not work for me, as NFS server was only listening on specific IP address, so I had to comment out this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../../../project", "/var/www", type: "nfs",:nfs => true
```

and put this instead:

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
  sudo mount 192.168.178.40:/d/project /var/www/ && sudo mount 192.168.178.40:/d/project/_conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled && sudo service apache2 restart
SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: false, run: "always"
```

,where 192.168.178.40 is the IP where NFS ports are open. You can scan it from yout gurest OS with, e.g. nmap.

3. And you'll also need to install vagrant plugin called vagrant-winnfsd. It can be done by:

> vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a problem with twig performance but directory sharing in VirtualBox/vagrant. Try to enable I/O caching in VirtualBox.

Comment: Currently I'm working on VirtualBox and after unsuccessful "fixes" (same problem) I move code to VM and share it to windows through Samba...

Comment: you were right about I/O performance, but I'll answer my question now, perhaps it will be useful for someone