# How do I use rsync shared folders in Vagrant on Windows WITHOUT Cygwin?

Tags: windows, symfony, vagrant, rsync

More than two weeks I've been trying with no success so far to find out how to speedup vagrant box containing huge projects based on Symfony/Laravel/FuelPHP on Windows 8.1.

The problem is Windows doesn't have native ways to sync/share folders between host/guest machines with acceptable performance. Unison/winnfs solutions seem not work on my system while I get tons of different errors related to network/filesystem/whatever. So, the last hope was Rsync. I know, there is Cygwin, MinGW and other tools that bring rsync support in Windows. But I don't want to use them. I don't want to turn my system into software-scrapyard. However, I don't want to switch to any linux distro just to have ability to work on my projects.

So, finally, my question is:

**Is there any way on Windows to just install Vagrant (and any plugins), VirtualBox and bring my application to life with no such huge loading gaps, and keeping system clean.**

Comment: Have you tried to put the project files in the Vagrant box ? Then you'll be able to edit files by using the shared folder, performance won't be an issue since you'll access a few files at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean creating base box containing project files?

Comment: I don't know what are *base box*, I'm sorry. This question is unclear, where did you put your project files? Is the Vagrant guest accessing PHP files which are located on the host system?

Comment: My workflow is plain and simple: I run `vagrant up` in my project folder, which is shared with guest machine, or synced over _SMB_. The problem is, this types of folders linking have major performance issues, so project (thousands of files when using any framework in development mode, i.e. without compiling/caching) is loaded too slow.

Comment: You can use `vagrant up` to create a Vagrant box, then install (copy files, use git, etc.) project files in the Vagrant box. It should be faster.

Comment: Yes, I did it many times, but the problem is still here: I have to edit my app files, so I have to sync its folder to the host machine. Moreover, I want to have ability to manage project git on my host with phpstorm, for example. Sshfs is not the solution due to file corruptions (especially git files) while sync.

Comment: If you share the files from the guest to the host they will appear as local files so you'll be able to use PhpStorm, etc.

Comment: See [Symfony2 and Twig performance in a vagrant box](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27100713/2257664).