# Common session.save_handler for all projects

Tags: php, symfony, session, vagrant

I'm using vagrant virtual machine for local PHP development and I noticed that there are session write issues when using vagrant-winnfsd plugin. The plugin serves fine my needs, that's why I don't want to reconfigure vagrant, but rather solve the read/write problem. I don't know the origin of the problem, but it's exactly the same as described [here](https://ctors.net/2014/04/21/symfony_slow_in_vagrant). For me `SessionHandler::read()` also takes about 120 seconds to complete on every request.

So as the author suggest, it makes sense to reconfigure session handler to use either RDDBM or Memcache storage. That sounds reasonable, but I don't want to do this in every single project, I just want to configure it once in php.ini since it has `session.save_handler` parameter and it can be set to database or memcache there.

I don't mind having one PHP class with all `::read()`, `::write()` and others methods, main thing is having this code in one place.

Is that possible?

**UPDATE:** I found the reason and really thanks to @Jasper N. Brouwer they were storing in a NFS sync'd folder. The cause was that I did not add `prod` environment into AppKernel.php "vagrant" fix. So it used to be:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test', ''))) {
        return '/run/shm/appname/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return '/run/shm/appname/logs';
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```

and was ok in `dev` env, but not in `prod`. Should be:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test', 'prod'))) {
        return '/run/shm/appname/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test', 'prod'))) {
        return '/run/shm/appname/logs';
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```

**HOWEVER**, just out of curiosity and for easier debugging, since we have now this bounty, I still find the common session save handler for the whole PHP server a nice idea. This may be useful in development if I have to save it into a DB and then can view session data for all projects in realtime in a database using my GUI tool. Maybe, it's possible to do it using `auto_prepend_file` setting? And define save hanlder there, but I'm not sure how to disallow override of it later in any project code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sessions

A simpler solution is to keep using the `files` session save handler, but have it use a directory that is *not* a Vagrant "synced folder".

In other words, set `session.save_path` to `/tmp` for example. This could be any directory, as long as it's not a synced folder (like `/vagrant`). And you could indeed do this in your `php.ini`.

It's even better to use a directory that's actually a shared memory directory (`/dev/shm`), which is in-memory storage (not on-disk). On most Linux distributions `/tmp` is actually a folder inside `/dev/shm`.

PS: I had a similar problem where session writes would produce empty files. I too wasn't able to track down the source of this problem (other than it had something to do with Vagrant synced folders using NFS), so after a while I gave up searching and simply did what I described above.

## Other write-heavy operations

Because Vagrant NFS mounts are relatively slow, I recommend to perform other write-heavy operations outside of the synced folders as well.

Examples of write-heavy things are cache systems:

- Doctrine 2 may use a file cache driver for metadata-, query- and result-cache.
- Doctrine 2 will write Proxies in development mode.
- Twig will "compile" templates to raw php files.
- Symfony 2 will cache various things in files.
- A lot of others

Another example is loggers. Logs will commonly be written to files, which happens a lot.

Unfortunately there's no real way to configure these directories on a server-wide basis, because it all depends on what components are used, what needs to be configured, which is very project-specific.

## Possible Symfony 2 solution

You could try a sort of hack to have Symfony 2 use a cache- and logs-directory using environment variables.

Set an environment variables like so:

```
export VENDORNAME_PHP_CACHE_ROOT_DIR='/dev/shm/vendorname/cache'
export VENDORNAME_PHP_LOGS_ROOT_DIR='/dev/shm/vendorname/logs'
```

This will make sure CLI tools can pick those variables up.
You might want to do this in your `.bashrc` or something like it.

You might have to duplicate this in the configuration of your web-server:

For Apache

```
SetEnv VENDORNAME_PHP_CACHE_ROOT_DIR /dev/shm/vendorname/cache
SetEnv VENDORNAME_PHP_LOGS_ROOT_DIR /dev/shm/vendorname/logs
```

For Nginx

```
fastcgi_param VENDORNAME_PHP_CACHE_ROOT_DIR /dev/shm/vendorname/cache;
fastcgi_param VENDORNAME_PHP_LOGS_ROOT_DIR /dev/shm/vendorname/logs;
```

Then you can edit the `getCacheDir()` and `getLogDir()` methods of `AppKernel.php` like so:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if ($dir = $this->getDir('VENDORNAME_PHP_CACHE_ROOT_DIR')) {
        return $dir;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if ($dir = $this->getDir('VENDORNAME_PHP_LOGS_ROOT_DIR')) {
        return $dir;
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}

private function getDir($variable)
{
    if (!in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return;
    }

    if (!($rootDir = getenv($variable))) {
        return;
    }

    return sprintf('%s/appname/%s', $rootDir, $this->environment);
}
```

Now you can control the cache- and logs-directories of all Symfony 2 projects through those environment variables.

For other projects you can do something similar.

But you'll have to do a bit of tweaking in the projects themselves. Because this is *not* native PHP functionality (like `session.save_path` is), there's no way to control this through PHP configuration (`php.ini` alone).

Comment: See this: http://prntscr.com/7fms8v , there is php.ini loaded by Apache2, namely session.save_path which is currently /tmp, screenshot of access rights for /tmp in vagrant and a screenshot of Vagrantfile where you can see that /tmp is NOT synced at all

Comment: BTW, I saw this article a while ago and performed the proposed changes earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100713/symfony2-and-twig-performance-in-a-vagrant-box

Comment: Are you saying that `/tmp` (a non synced folder) is used, but session reading/writing is still slow? Can you run `var_dump(ini_get('session.save_handler'));` and `var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));` in the web-app to confirm the settings in use?

Comment: Also, are you sure the session is slow? Or is it something else? Have you benchmarked / profiled yourself? (I ask this because the other SO question you refer to is about Twig, not sessions.)

Comment: see my update, I used newrelic as a profiler and the issue is kind of solved now, but I'm wondering if it's possible to have save handler configured for the whole PHP setup for easier debugging (See "However" section of my update)

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this explains some things better. I'm also not sure the suggested solution will suffice, but I'm afraid what you want isn't (easily) possible.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I voted it up, if there is nothing new in the next 5 days, it will be auto-awarded to you, if you don't mind! I made the changes, actually, after I figured out I had prod environment which was not included in my earlier changes, it works reasonably faster now. However, I was hoping to have a generinc solution. For example, today I got a new Laravel project and session has been configured for filesystem by default. Until I changed it to memcached, it failed with the error. So it takes some time to figure out session config options for every new project

Comment: There is nothing generic about the code you altered. It is Symfony 2 specific. So indeed you'll need a slightly different solution for a Laravel project. There's really nothing you can do about it.

Comment: And are you aware that when a bounty is auto-awarded, only _half of it_ is? (not complaining, just checking ;)

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you. Thanks for your help! I tried to make an auto_prepend_script with custom session handler and session_start, which is essentially session_autostart, but symfony projects (and I assume other frameworks too) won't work with session_autostart, so seems that you're right it's impossible